# onMapReady is not called even though the map display without any error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i am building a tracking map that contains two markers one of the current location and the second get its LatLng from the database server it works well from two weeks, now it display only the map without any markers and when i try to debug the app and put a break point to onMapReady() function, i found that it isn't called

Layout.XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/Defualt">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/left_arrow_icon"
                android:onClick="goBack"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Track"
                android:textColor="@color/Defualt" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>





</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, RoutingListener {

    @Nullable
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private List<Polyline> polylines;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    private LatLng pickupLocation, patientLocation;

    private Marker pickupMarker;

    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StatusBar.setStatusBarGradiant(MapsActivity.this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used
        polylines = new ArrayList<>();

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        pickupLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                        pickupMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(pickupLocation)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_point))
                                .anchor(0.5f,0.5f));

                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pickupLocation));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

                        Log.i("mapCurrentLoc", location.getLatitude()+ ", " + location.getLongitude());
                        if (location != null) {
                            // Logic to handle location object
                        }
                    }
                });



        MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.map_style);
        mMap.setMapStyle(style);


        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);




        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            }else{
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }

        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mSecondLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }
```

Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.dtri"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
//    compileOptions {
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    // navigation menu
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01'
    // circle image library
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    // for FCM _ push notification
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'


    implementation 'com.github.stankoutils:app:1.3.10'
    implementation 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation project(path: ':infinitecycleviewpager')


    implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    // google map
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'


    //implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.6'
//    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.10.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the screen taken when it works as i want
[image]

current result of map
[image]

Comment: any error logs?

Comment: @PavelPoley : No

Answer (score 0):

Your onMapReady function is being called. What is happening here is that the permissions haven't been granted on your device and hence you immediately break out of the function.

You can test this yourself as follows:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Log.i("mapReady", "map is ready");

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("permissionDenied", "no permission");
        return;
    }

    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
    ...
}
```

You should be able to see both "map is ready" and "no permission" in your log. Allowing location access on the device from where you're running your app should fix your map.

Hope this helps!